# Grails - import jsch results in "package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist"

Tags: java, grails, import

I'm porting some java code into GRAILS framework and I keep getting this error when importing libraries (jcraft):

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;

MyServiceImpl.java:47: package com.jcraft.jsch does not exist
  [groovyc] import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
  [groovyc] ^
```

I've tried adding this to 'BuildConfig.groovy', but still same error.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.43'
```

Any idea what I need to add? I also added the actual jar file in the Build path library. Many thanks.

Comment: do you have any repository-related error ? They specify a particular repo on the JSCH site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to copy this library into the lib folder of the grails-app structure and removed all refernces from e.g. BuildConfig.groovy ...

i can also try to unpack the library and check if the lib-structure is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing this and that fixed the problem. Still doesn't explain why that particular import wouldn't work.

Comment: I think it might be the problem with jar file loaded from Maven repo: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/ looks like 0.1.43 was corrupt (3KB and only contains MET-INF). If you would try to fetch other version through BuildConfig it should work and is a better approach than having it in /lib dir